# Unable to print altered text taken from a file to an output file in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

I'm trying to take some text from a file, alter it based on some rules, and print this altered text into a new file.

Here are the rules:

> For any line of text between `""` (dialogue), apply the following:
>
> 1. If there is a vowel followed by `r`, change the `r` to an `h` (ex. `harbor` become `hahboh`)
> 2. If a words ends with `a` append an `r` (ex. `Canada` become `Canadar`) This
>    does not apply to `a` by itself (ex. `I saw a dog` is unchanged)
> 3. If the word `very` is present, swap it with `wicked`
> 4. If the word ends in `r` and is preceded by `i` or `ee`, swap the `r` with `yah` (`seer` becomes `seeyah`, `air` become `aiyah`).
> 5. If the word ends with `r` and is preceded by `oo`, change the `r` to `wah` (ex `door` become `doowah`)

Please note that for rules 4 and 5, they only apply if the word ENDS in r, while 1 applies to any instance of r following a vowel. So reservoir becomes reservoiyah (since the er follows 1, while the ir follows 4)

While I can open the files, and even print from the source file just fine, the text in the output file remains unaltered, so that it's simply a copy of the source.

I think the most likely issue is the second, but I'm not sure how to solve it (Since I tested the methods on regular strings, so I know they work):

1. I'm reading the text as a string that can't be altered so the edits aren't being made
2. The text is not recognizing that dialogue is present, so it doesn't make any alterations.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define LENGTH 500

//function prototypes
void processDialogue(FILE *file,char *dialogue);
int isVowel(char c);
void a_add_r(char word[]);
void very_to_wicked(char word[]);
void special_rules(char word[]);
void r_to_h(char word[]);

int main() {
     FILE *input = fopen("sherlock.txt", "r"); 
    FILE *output = fopen("southie-sherlock.txt", "w");

    if (input == NULL){
        puts("The input file could not be opened");
        fclose(input);
        fclose(output);
    }

    if(output == NULL){
        puts("The output file could not be opened");
        fclose(input);
        fclose(output);
    }

    char line_to_read[LENGTH];  
    char edited_line[LENGTH]; 
    int between_quotes = 0; // Marks if we are within dialogue or not

    while (fgets(line_to_read, LENGTH, input) != NULL) {
        int length = strlen(line_to_read);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (line_to_read[i] == '"') {
                if (between_quotes == 0) {
                    // If inside dialogue, process the dialogue
                    between_quotes = 1;
                    strncpy(edited_line, line_to_read, i + 1);
                    edited_line[i + 1] = '\0';
                    processDialogue(output, edited_line);
                } else {
                    // If starting dialogue, set the flag
                    between_quotes = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (between_quotes == 1) {
            // If dialogue spans multiple lines without explicit quotes, process the remaining text
            strncpy(edited_line, line_to_read, length);
            edited_line[length] = '\0';
            processDialogue(output, edited_line);
        } else {
            // If no dialogue, print the original line
            fputs(line_to_read, output);
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
    
void processDialogue(FILE *file, char *dialogue) {
    char *token = strtok(dialogue, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {

    special_rules(token);
    a_add_r(token);
    very_to_wicked(token);
    r_to_h(token);

    fprintf(file, "%s ", token);  // Replace this with writing to a file
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

int isVowel(char c){
    c = tolower(c);
    if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i'||c == 'o'|| c == 'u'){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void very_to_wicked(char word[]){
    if(strcmp(word, "very") == 0){
            strcpy(word, "wicked");
            }
}

//Applies special rules 
void special_rules(char word[]) {
    int length = strlen(word);
    if (length > 2 && word[length - 1] == 'r') {
        if ((word[length - 2] == 'e' && word[length - 3] == 'e') || word[length - 2] == 'i') {
            strcpy(word + length - 1, "yah");
        } else if (word[length - 2] == 'o' && word[length - 3] == 'o') {
            strcpy(word + length - 1, "wah");
        }
    }
}

//Replaces any r's after a vowel with h
void r_to_h(char word[]){
    int length = strlen(word);
    if(length > 1){
        for(int i = 0; i<length-1; i++){
            int vowel = isVowel(word[i]);
            if(vowel == 1 && word[i+1]== 'r'){
                word[i+1] = 'h';
            }
        }
    }
}

//Add an r to a word that ends with a
void a_add_r(char word[]){
    int length = strlen(word);
    if(length > 1){
        if(word[length - 1] == 'a'){
            strcat(word, "r");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of how the text is formatted. There can be multiple instances of dialogue, and dialogue can extend across multiple lines, which has made checking for dialogue less straightforward:

```
“Well, I found my plans very seriously menaced. It looked as if the
pair might take an immediate departure, and so necessitate very prompt
and energetic measures on my part. At the church door, however, they
separated, he driving back to the Temple, and she to her own house. ‘I
shall drive out in the park at five as usual,’ she said as she left
him. I heard no more. They drove away in different directions, and I
went off to make my own arrangements.”

“Which are?”

“Some cold beef and a glass of beer,” he answered, ringing the bell. “I
have been too busy to think of food, and I am likely to be busier still
this evening. By the way, Doctor, I shall want your co-operation.”
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You have conflicting rules. If the word ends with "ir", both rules 1 and 4 apply.

Comment: How is the "a by itself" exception relevant for the condition in rule 4? I think that was supposed to be in rule 2.

Comment: When you see the starting quote, you need to call `process_dialogue()` on the part of the line *after* the quote. You're copying the part up to the quote to `edited_line`, not the part after.

Comment: `if ((input =fopen("sherlock.txt", "r")) == NULL || (output = fopen("southie-sherlock.txt", "w")) == NULL)`Ouch.  Who is teaching you to write code like that?  Cramming that much into one line makes it very hard to see what's going on.  That makes your job of making the code do what you want a lot harder.  It also makes it impossible to tell which of the `fopen()` calls failed.  **And** if the second call to `fopen()` fails, you won't close the first opened `FILE`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry that one wasn't quite clear. The vowels rule applies to any instance or a vowel appearing before the letter r, so irrigate would have the r after the first i changed. The other rule only applies to if the word ends with r, so fir would implement the second since the word ends with r.

Comment: When you do `strcpy(word, "wicked")` you're writing past the end of `word`. If it's not the last word in the line, it will overwrite the beginning of the next word. And if it's the last word in the line you may write past the end of `edited_line`, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: You have similar problems in some of the other rules.

Comment: You should copy the word into a buffer that's long enough to hold the modified word, rather than updating it in place.